# Printing margin size of all windows

Tags: window

I am writing a minor mode that changes the margin width when multiple windows are shown at fullscreen.

I would like to list the values of the margin sizes for each window in a frame using elisp code.  What can I do ?  Margin Sizes can be set with `set-window-margins`.  But do not see what will be needed to access the values.

Comment: What do you mean by "print" (and where) and "margin size"? Please specify clearly what you want to do/ask.

Comment: May I ask why you need to do this? We may be able to show you a better path towards accomplishing what you need. In addition, please edit the question to also explain the format in which you would like the result. For instance, do you want it logged to the Messages buffer? Is that good enough?

Comment: Logging to the messages buffer would be enough.

Comment: If you had looked for `set-window-margins` in the Emacs Lisp Ref manual, you would see that there is another function described right under it: `window-margins`. Then to loop over all the windows, use `window-list`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a function that will maximize a frame and set the margins unconditionally on all windows that are visible at the time in that frame, as long as more than one window is displayed, which is *almost* what you asked for.

```
(defun marginalize-these ()
  "Maximize current frame and sets margins on all currently-displayed windows in that frame. Also prints pre-change values to the messages buffer, because why not."
  (interactive)
  (set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 'maximized)
  (let ((displayed-windows (seq-filter 'window-live-p (window-list))))
    (if (> (length displayed-windows) 1)
        (dolist (window displayed-windows)
          (message "%s" (window-margins window))
          (set-window-margins window 30 30)))))
```

I chose 30 for left and right margins arbitrarily.

I didn't make this a minor mode because it's unclear from what you describe what you need the holistic behavior to be. For instance:

- what happens if a new window appears in that frame?
- what happens if a window is shown in two frames?
- what happens if a window stops showing in one frame and starts showing in another frame?

So, a one-off function seemed a better fit for the need you described.

Comment: The information would be applicable only to the current working frame.

Comment: @Dilna That is correct.